# Help with Swap Partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, swap, data-loss

(Translated from spanish)

I accidentally marked a 136GB partition which has some files in it as swap space during installation. Can I access these files? Can I change the partition type without having to reformat?

Comment: He traducido al inglés a su pregunta ya que la mayoría de los usuarios de aquí no entienden español. Si tiene problemas para entender Inglés, usted puede usar Google Translate o nos dicen lo mismo, así que alguien puede traducir el answerss para su conveniencia

Comment: en: I have translated your question to English since most users here don't understand spanish. If you have problem understanding English, you may either use Google translate or tell us the same, so that someone can translate the answerss for your convinience

Comment: Added some tags for clarity

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to make sure that you don't use that partition. Unmount it straight away if you are running the installed OS. Or just turn off the PC.

Boot from a utility disk with PARTED on it and mark the partition as whatever it was before, probably EXT2/3 if it was Linux. Then mount the partition and see if you can read the data. There is a reasonable chance that most of the data will be ok.

However, when you did the installation, there is also a good chance that the installer actually formatted the partition. If this is the case, it is less likely that the data can be recovered. But you can use a partition undelete tool to try. If you've done the above, unmount, put the partition type back to swp then run the undelete partition tool & follow the instructions.

There are too many partition undelete tools to list here but I did a quick [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=partition%20undelete&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=F8J&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=partition%20undelete%20ext&oq=partition%20undelete%20ext&gs_l=serp.3..0i8i30l4.25747.26488.0.28275.4.4.0.0.0.0.281.813.0j2j2.4.0...0.0.YISNQgNBCs8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=853bac6d7e512bb7&biw=1221&bih=727) which returned a load of useful links.

Recommended recovery boot OS's:

- [Knoppix](http://knoppix.org)
- [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage)
- [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)